# Magento tax rates multiple countries

Tags: magento, countries

I whant to change our Magento CE 1.7 Shop to an multistore. So 2 countires an each has its own store but based on same products.

Now the 2nd country has different tax rates but the gross price should be same in both shops.

I have set the tax calucations based on the current county (set in system-config). So each Shop takes the corrent tax rates. And of course changed the tax reates for the 2nd country.

But now the gross prices in the shop are different. Even the product prices are set to be already including the tax rates. They get still recalculated.

e.g. county 1 has 19% tax and country 2 has 20%
Product 1 has a price of 70,90 in the backend and frontend. In country 2 its showing 71,50 in the frontend.

I dont want to set a new price for each product for the 2nd country. Isnt there a way to avoid the recalculation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I found the solution.

I also have to set in system -> sales -> shipping settings -> origin country to the other country. Its not enought to change the Default Tax Destination Calculation Country and define the tax rules.

Comment: I have the same problem but this can't be the solution. Although the price for the customer will be correct your tax balance in Magento will be off.

In my case 14.95 including tax is the price I want to charge. With dutch rates that's 14.10 without taxes (6% low), in germany the customer will pay the same but it should be 13.97 (7% low)

Answer (score 0):

To hold a specific price by website/view you would normally do a catalog->item->price , select the website/store view from the drop down (top left), select price tab, unselect use default value and change the price to what ever you wanted displayed.

Changing the Shipping/Origin Address controls which tax rate is assumed when the catalog price = including tax.

Otherwise the system dynamically re-calculates the price including tax by figuring out the price excluding tax and then applying the new stores/customer's tax rate.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at this, https://github.com/WMI/WMG_Tax , it recalculates the VAT properly.